# Creating an app similar to Facebook feed page

Tags: ios, facebook, uitableview

I'm just wondering what's the best way to do a screen that looks pretty much like  the feed view in the Facebook app. I guess the most obvious answer would be to use a UITableView but there are lot of challenges.

1. There are comments in every feed item and for that we will have to use another UITableView. And that means a UITableView sitting inside a UITableViewCell.
2. We can't re-use the cells as there are several different content types.
3. Determining the height of the cell is again a problem as that depends on the number of comments in a feed item.

I'm not planning to do an app that looks like Facebook but this is just a food for thought! I guess there is a better approach that using UITableView. What do you guys think ?

Comment: you got any idea to  implement this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can design this type of complex interfaces also with hard code but if the code is organised it will save you more time than taking the challenge of using UITableView.